# Prove that if $|G| = 160$, $G$ is not simple.

Tags: group-theory, proof-explanation, sylow-theory

I'm trying to prove this with Sylow's Theorem. I understand that the intersection between two Sylow-2 subgroups $H$ and $K$ cannot be of order $16$, since $| H \cap K| = 16$ implies $H \cap K \lhd G$. What I don't get, is how to proceed with the proof when $|H \cap K| = 8$. I did try to follow the proof at this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/103105/alternative-way-to-prove-that-a-group-of-order-160-is-not-simple) but I don't understand this part:

> Suppose there were $2$ distinct Sylow $2$-Subgroups, and even if remaining three subgroups  intersect in a group of order $8$, they are going to have too many elements.($24 \times 3+7+31 \times 2$=$141$ non-identity elements)

I think the calculation assumes that the three Sylow subgroups, say $S_1, S_2, S_3$, share the same intersection. But how can we be sure of this? Isn't it possible that $|S_1 \cap S_2| = 8$, $|S_2 \cap S_3| = 8$ but $S_1 \cap S_2 \neq S_2 \cap S_3$?

Comment: I can see you might want as an exercise to do it this way, but @Sebastian Schoennenbeck 's comment on your linked question gives the easiest (and most useful in other contexts) way to solve the question.

Answer (score 2):

Assume that $G$ is simple. Then it is easy to see that $n_2(G)=5$. So if $P \in Syl_2(G)$, then $|G:N_G(P)|=5$. $G$ acts by left multiplication on the left cosets of $N_G(P)$ and the kernel of this action is trivial, since $G$ is simple. It follows that $G$ can be embedded in $A_5$, violating $|G|=160$ not dividing $60=|A_5|$. See also [here](https://books.google.nl/books?id=E9kOCgAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover&hl=nl&source=gbs_ge_summary_r&cad=0#v=onepage&q&f=false), Theorem (1.1) if you are unfamiliar with this argument.

Comment: If $P$ is a Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$, then $|G:P|=5$ and $G$ acts on the left cosets of $P$ and then as you have.

Comment: Yes correct, $N_G(P)=P$ in this case.